# Flex/AIR + Catalyst: What's the best way to get them to talk to each other?

Tags: apache-flex, perl, web-services, air, catalyst

What is the best way to get Adobe Flex/AIR to communicate with perl [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/)?

We are currently using [Catalyst::Plugin::XMLRPC](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst::Plugin::XMLRPC) on the Catalyst side and [as3-rpclib](http://code.google.com/p/as3-rpclib/) on the Flex/AIR side.  That works fine, but I'd rather take as3-rpclib out of the picture and use a method that is native to Flex.

From what I can tell, it's native compnonents are HTTPService, WebService (SOAP), and RemoteObject.

Which one is the best fit in the Catalyst environment?

Also, could you point me to a nice "Hello World" example of the winner?  WSDLs make my head spin.

Answer (score 5):

SOAP and [Catalyst::Controller::SOAP](http://search.cpan.org/~druoso/Catalyst-Controller-SOAP-1.10/lib/Catalyst/Controller/SOAP.pm) look to be what you want.  It is based on XML::Compile::SOAP, which is "the good one".  The docs tell you how to make a WSDL into a service that your Catalyst app provides.

(If you want to go the other way, there is Catalyst::Model::SOAP, but I don't think that's what you want.)

If JSON is an option, you might consider that.  It is very easy to use with Catalyst::Controller::REST or Catalyst::View::JSON.